# Preencher Select baseado no valor de outro Select anterior

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, select

Olá, gostaria de inserir informações que estão em um banco de dados baseado no valor que o select está selecionado.

Baseado no valor que o input 'profissional' tivesse aparecia os serviços que estão cadastrados no banco de dados.

Vi alguns posts usando Ajax, Javascript, mas não consegui adaptar ao meu código, se alguém puder dar uma força. Se precisar de mais informações só avisar.

Desde já obrigado.

```
<form action="pages/inserts/insertagendamento.php" name="agendamento" method="post">
        
        <label for="data">Data:</label>
        <input id="data" name="data" type="date" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
        
        <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
        <input type="time" id="hora" name="hora">
        
        <label for="duracao">Duração:</label>
        <input type="time" id="duracao" name="duracao" placeholder="h:m"><br>
        
        
        <label for="profissional">Profissional:</label>
            <select id="profissional" name="profissional">
            <option =value="">Selecione a Profissional</option>
            <?php
            include ("conexao.php");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM profissionais";
            $pesquisa = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            
            while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($pesquisa)) {
                echo "<option value=" . $exibe["profissionais_id"] . "> ". $exibe["profissionais_nome"] . "</option> ";
            }
            ?>
            </select><br>
            
        <label for="servico">Servico:</label>
            <select id="servico" name="servico">
            <option value="">Selecione o serviço</option>
            
             Aqui seria oq preciso preencher

            </select>
            
        Cliente: <input type="text" name="cliente"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opa raphael, para resolver isso é bem simples, mas você vai precisar de um arquivo `.php` separado aguardando o filtro do primeiro select.

Para fazê-lo, você precisará enviar uma requisição usando ajax mesmo, vamos lá para o javascript:

```
var selectServicos = document.querySelector('#servico')

var selectProfissional = document.querySelector('#profissional')

selectProfissional.onchange = function(evento){ // função que vai ser executada cada vez que o valor do select for mudado, passando o evento como parametro
    var id_filtro = evento.target.value // pega o valor do evento, que vai ser o do select profissional

    fetch('seu-backend.php?id_filtro='+id_filtro) // faz a requisição para a url, passando o filtro como parâmetro
       .then(response => response.text()) // avisa que a proxima resposta da promise deve ser um texto
       .then(options => selectServicos.innerHTML = options)  // exibe os valores dentro do seu select, que foram retornados do seu backend
}
```

Pronto, com esse trecho de código você já irá enviar a requisição para o arquivo do backend, agora vamos para ele:

```
$id_filtro = $_GET['id_filtro'];

include ("conexao.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE seu_filtro = $id_filtro";
$pesquisa = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($pesquisa)) {
    echo "<option value=" . $exibe["valor"] . "> ". $exibe["valor"] . "</option> ";
}
die;
```

E pronto, seu código já irá funcionar. Vale lembrar que esse `die` no final é necessário, para ter certeza que não vai ter nenhum HTML a mais do que o que queremos. Outro ponto interessante é deixar o `error_reporting(0)` para ele não atrapalhar no seu retorno.

Esse código também está meio vulnerável, já que como estamos filtrando a partir de um dado do cliente, alguém com mais conhecimento pode tentar dar um SQL injection ou passar um valor indesejado. Ai cabe a você fazer uma tratativa.

Espero ter ajudado!! :)

Comment: Muito obrigado mano, deu certo aqui, com esse seu código foi muito mais fácil entender (:

Comment: e quanto a segurança sem problema, é um sisteminha que estou fazendo só para uso 'doméstico' digamos assim, mas muito obrigado de novo

Comment: Ah show então mano! feliz em ajudar :)